# How can I use multiple condition in python np.select(numpy.select)

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to express the following using `np.select`.

0 if FBG is less than 100 or HbA1c is less than 5.7

1 if FBG is greater than or equal to 100 and less than 126 or HbA1c is greater than or equal to 5.7 and less than 6.5;

If FBG is 126 or higher or HbA1c is 6.5 or higher 2.

```
CondList = [
    (data['FBG'] < 100) | (data['HbA1c'] < 5.7), 
    ((data['FBG'] < 126) & (data['FBG'] >= 100)) | ((data['HbA1c'] < 6.5) & (data['HbA1c'] >= 5.7)),
    (data['FBG'] >= 126) | (data['HbA1c'] >= 6.5)]
ChoiceList = [0,1,2]
data.insert(1,'DM',np.select(CondList,ChoiceList,default=3))
```

When I wrote it like the code above, there was no error, but when I checked the result, I could confirm that the classification was not done properly.

[image]

In the result image above, in the 92423th, DM should be 1 because the FBG is 100 or more, but you can see that it is classified as 0.
The same is true for the 92425th.

How can I modify the code to achieve the desired result?

Any method other than `np.select` is also fine.

---

I solved this problem by referencing the comments and changing the order of the conditions. I'll leave the modified code for anyone with the same problem as me.

```
CondList = [
   (data['FBG'] >= 126) | (data['HbA1c'] >= 6.5),
    ((data['FBG'] < 126) & (data['FBG'] >= 100)) | ((data['HbA1c'] < 6.5) & (data['HbA1c'] >= 5.7)),
    (data['FBG'] < 100) | (data['HbA1c'] < 5.7)]
ChoiceList = [2,1,0]
data.insert(1,'DM',np.select(CondList,ChoiceList,default=3))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a wrongly classified array, with code to create that array?

Comment: sorry. I've edited the post because I thought the question was confusing. I've also uploaded an example of a misclassified array to the post.

Comment: 92423th is 0 because HbA1c is 5.4 which is less than 5.7. So this is correctly classified. Same for 92425th

Comment: Oh, I'm a fool... 0 is correct because HbA1c is 5.4, but 1 is also correct because FBG is 103. I realized that my code is fine for classifying 0 and 2, but not suitable for classifying 1. Thank you!

Comment: [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html): "When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used."

Comment: I see. thank you for telling me. Is there any other function suitable for the condition I want?

Comment: I solved the problem by reading your comment and reordering the condition. Thank you so much!